# Why is my function returning None instead of my key values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value-store

I want to make a function that returns a tuple of adjacent positions. But I'm having trouble returning the dictionary values.

My code:

```
def creat_position(c,r):
if isinstance(c, str) and c in ('a', 'b', 'c') and isinstance(r, str) and l in ('1', '2', '3'):
    return c, r

def position_to_str(pos):
    c = str(obtain_pos_c(pos))
    r = str(obtain_pos_r(pos))

    if its_position(pos):
       return c + r

def obtain_adjacent_positions(pos):
 
    """
    obtain_adjacent_positions: position -> tuple of positions
    """

    p = position_to_str(pos)
     #'b''2' -> 'b2'

    adj = {'a1': ('b1', 'a2'),
           'b1': ('a1', 'b2', 'c1'),
           'c1': ('b1', 'c2'),
           'a2': ('a1', 'b2', 'a3'),
           'b2': ('b1', 'a2', 'c2', 'b3'),
           'c2': ('c1', 'b2', 'c3'),
           'a3': ('a2', 'b3'),
           'b3': ('b2', 'a3', 'c3'),
           'c3': ('c2', 'b3')
           }
    adjacents = adj[p]
    return adjacent
```

The output should be:

```
>>>p1 = creat_positon('c', '1')

>>>p2 = creat_positon('b', '3')

>>>position_to_str(p2)

'b3'

>>>tuple(position_to_str(p) for p in obtain_adjacent_positions(p1))

('b1', 'c2')

>>>tuple(position_to_str(p) for p in obtain_adjacent_positions(p2))

('b2', 'a3', 'c3')
```

The problem is when I run my function this happens:

```
>>>tuple(position_to_str(p) for p in obtain_adjacent_positions(p2))

(None, None, None)
```

Instead of my key values.

Comment: In your own words, when you do `position_to_str(p2)`, do you expect the value of `p2` to *change*? How? Why?

Comment: I add more code to help understand the function. It can change and it depends on what values I put on my creat_position(pos)

Comment: just glancing at your code, you have `if its_position(pos):`.... well what if *not* that? Then it will return `None`

Comment: Didn't had that function here. Returns a boolean, true or false.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and carefully trace through your code. Try checking, for example, what `p` is equal to immediately before attempting to get `adj[p]`. Is it what you expect? If not, then step backwards and try to explain it.

Comment: I've tried this. My p should be my dictionary keys

Answer (score 1):

The keys in the dictionary are strings, but your code tries to look up a "position", which I assume is an object.

You could either pass it to the function as a string:

```
tuple(position_to_str(p) for p in obtain_adjacent_positions(position_to_str(p2)))
```

Or have the function do it itself:

```
adjacents = adj[position_to_str(p)]
```

Comment: Good, the second aproache `adjacents = adj[position_to_str(p)]` is more practical.

Comment: It still returns (None, None,None) instead of  ('b2', 'a3', 'c3'). When i make a print(adjacents = adj[position_to_str(pos)]) it gives me the values,but with this 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'